# jquery duplicate spans when append is used with fadeOut()

Tags: jquery-plugins

This is really strange, when I run this code i get 2 span.

```
$('#_login input').fadeOut('fast', function(){                                                              
$('#_login').append('<span id="bob_login_err" style="color:orange;font-size:10px;">Could not log in</span>').fadeIn('fast');});
```

Comment: first you can not append span inside input

Comment: that is not what i'm doing, have a closer look

Comment: can u make script as code so it could be readable

Comment: that's beacause you have 2 input inside `#_login` i guesse login and password

Comment: see this: http://jsfiddle.net/bgccm/

Comment: Yes of course! Two inputs is correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

that's beacause you have 2 input inside #_login i guesse login and password:

try this:

HTML:

```
<div id="_login">
    <div class="inputHolder"><!--Put The 2 input inside a div-->
        <input type="text" value="" name="login"/>
        <input type="text" value="" name="password"/>
    </div>
</div>​
```

JS:

```
     $('#_login .inputHolder').fadeOut('fast', function(){
$('#_login').append('<span id="bob_login_err" style="color:orange;font-size:10px;">not could not log in</span>').fadeIn('fast');
                                            });​
```